# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. for running an application

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried to run [this](https://github.com/z358z358/learning-laravel-5) project but get follow error by running `composer install` as developer said

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.4].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laracasts/flash 1.3.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.4].
    - Installation request for laracasts/flash 1.3.3 -> satisfiable by laracasts/flash[1.3.3].
```

composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
        "illuminate/html": "~5.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "~1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Seems the version of Laravel used in this project is dev.
Can you please tell me how can I run this project? I've no problem with installing a fresh Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is missing **mcrypt** extension - install and enable it and it will work.